# Gap at the top of UIScrollView on iOS10

Tags: ios9, ios10, nslayoutconstraint

I'm having an issue with constraints on a UIScrollView which appears to be iOS10-specific. I seem to have a gap between the top of the scroll view and the content view on the inside, which is supposed to be stuck to the top.

There doesn't appear to be any gap on iOS 9, but on iOS 10 the gap appears.
To be clear, in both cases the scroll view top is pinned to the bottom of the top layout guide, which lines up with the bottom of the navigation bar perfectly. iOS 10 introduces a gap the size of the navigation bar between the top of the scroll view and the top of the content view.

I could align the top of the scroll view to the top of the top layout guide, which would put the gap underneath the navigation bar and the content view would line up fine, but on iOS 9 the content view would be underneath the navigation bar which is undesirable.

I've quickly created some playground code which demonstrates the issue below. Is there something obvious I'm missing? What changed in iOS 10 to make this an issue, and how do I work around it?

[image: comparison of screenshots from iPhone 5s simulator]

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    var mainScrollView: UIScrollView
    var contentView: UIView

    init() {
        self.mainScrollView = UIScrollView()
        self.contentView = UIView()

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.mainScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        self.mainScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.view.addSubview(self.mainScrollView)
        self.mainScrollView.addSubview(self.contentView)

        // constrain the scroll view bounds to the view
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.mainScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.mainScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.bottomLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.mainScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.mainScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        // constrain the content view bounds to the scroll view
        self.mainScrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.mainScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.mainScrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.mainScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.mainScrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.mainScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.mainScrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.mainScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        // constrain the content view's size to the view's size
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    }
}

let rootViewController = TestViewController()
rootViewController.title = "Test"

let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = navigationController.view
```

Comment: I have the same issue... occurring only in iOS 10. Have you had any luck fixing it?

Comment: @inorganik - No, not yet. Just sort of moving on with the project an leaving it in place for now. Might end up having to put in an OS version check, which I'm hoping to avoid.

Comment: Added the solution I found as an answer, hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in iOS, if you have not created a bug for it yet, may worth submit one here https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

In the first constraint you are setting you set it to the `topLayoutGuide` `bottom`. So from Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621367-toplayoutguide) the `bottom` of the `topLayoutGuide` depend of the way you stack your subviews.  So in your example if you set it to

`self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.mainScrollView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))` it works.

But I regularly use the top of my subview so that I don't have "margin". So it could look like: `self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.mainScrollView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm away from my computer so I can't double check at the moment, but I'm pretty sure if I set it to the top of the top layout guide it does indeed work on iOS 10, but on iOS 9 it ends up behind the navigation bar, which I'm trying to avoid, which is why I didn't go with aligning it to the top of the superview.

Comment: Just to add to this, the top of the scroll view is in the location I want it to be on both iOS 9 and iOS 10: In line with the bottom of the navigation bar. The issue is the gap between the top of the scroll view and the top of the content view. If I move the scroll view to the top of the top layout guide, on iOS 10 the top of the scroll view is underneath the navigation bar and the content view is in line with the navigation bar. On iOS 9, the content view is also underneath the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, in my case for a UISearchController, where the adding of the view was done dynamically so I wouldn't have occasion to add constraints. I just had to manually set the `contentInset` of the scroll view (which in my case was a table view) and set it to the distance from the top of the screen you want. For you it might look like this:

```
// status bar + nav bar = 64
self.mainScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0);
self.view.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Please note I adapted this to swift from my Obj. C code so apologies if it's slightly off. I tested in iOS 9 and 10 and it looked right in both.